# Install Linux VM on Microsoft Hyper-V VM

Tags: linux, virtualbox, virtual-machine, vmware, virtualization

I have a VPS with Windows Server 2012 and it's one of the multiple Micrsoft Hyper-V virtual machines that exists on the server.

What I want to achieve:

Install a virtual machine with Linux.

I am not able to install a virtual machine with Linux inside this Hypver-V virtual machine, it's causing errors when installing. I've read a couple articles as well and they are stating that it isn't possible, because I'm trying to install a VM inside a VM.

Is this true?

I really want to do this without using a dedicated server or another VPS.

Answer (score 0):

It's probably impossible with Windows Server 2012 as the (root?) host, but with current Windows 10 and the upcoming Windows Server 2016:
https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/virtualization/hyperv_on_windows/user_guide/nesting

I am not sure if you can nest it like Hyper-V -> KVM though.

Btw, you can still run qemu / virtualbox without virtualization/acceleration (pure emulation, which can be practically unusable because it's too slow) inside a Hyper-V Linux VM anyway.

Answer (score 0):

I would expect the answer to be no, the hypervisor requires processors with Intel-VT or AMD-V to essentially allow the hypervisor to let the vms communicate to the processors. If the Hypervisor is already being presented with CPUs as virtual objects, they don't have the full Intel-VT or AMD-V features available (because your base Server 2012 R2 VM doesn't see the physical processor, only what its hypervisor is presenting to it).

Basically, by having a VM on a hypervisor and trying to allocate resources that have been allocated to the VM to a nested VM with the top level VM acting as the layer-2 hypervisor will not work well/at all.